# Enable ssl/https on IIS Express from scratch without visual studio

Tags: .net, https, iis-express, wcf-security

Is there any tutorial or can anyone tell me how to enable ssl/https on IIS Express without VS ? I am using sharpdevelop to make a WCF service and I would like to test the service with IIS Express with https enabled, but on the Web I only find methods to enable ssl using VS.

Thanks in advance for all your help

Greetings

Comment: Jexus Manager is there, and far better than Visual Studio, http://jexusmanager.com but you probably need to find a copy of applicationHost.config to get started.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express behind the scenes is still IIS. If you are magically using it without Visual Studio, find the configuration folder (it should be here C:\Users[username]\Documents\IISExpress) and edit applicationhost.config. You can try to configure bindings/sites there. A binding should look like this:

```
<site name="SomeApp" id="1">
<application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="c:\myapp" />
</application>
<bindings>
    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:localhost" />
    <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44300:localhost" />
</bindings>
```

Comment: That folder and files might not exist if you don't have Visual Studio installed and you do not have at least a web project created and launched. And it is also only used by old Visual Studio releases prior to 2015.

Comment: If that is all that needs to be done, it seems to be easy. But, what about server's certificate ? Will it be generated automatically ?

Comment: BTW, i use SharpDevelop to program .Net and C#. It can configure a web project to use IIS Express, but it seems it cannot handle SSL stuff